# Can PARAM-VALUE contain spaces?

Tags: unix, syslog

Reading [syslog rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424)

```
6.3.3. SD-PARAM

   Each SD-PARAM consists of a name, referred to as PARAM-NAME, and a
   value, referred to as PARAM-VALUE.
```

Can param-value contain spaces? or it has to be a one-word name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the rest of that section:

> To support international characters, the PARAM-VALUE field MUST be 
>   encoded using UTF-8.  A syslog application MAY issue any valid UTF-8
>   sequence.  A syslog application MUST accept any valid UTF-8 sequence
>   in the "shortest form".  It MUST NOT fail if control characters are
>   present in PARAM-VALUE.  The syslog application MAY modify messages
>   containing control characters (e.g., by changing an octet with value 0
>   (USASCII NUL) to the four characters "#000").  For the reasons
>   outlined in UNICODE TR36 [UNICODE-TR36], section 3.1, an originator
>   MUST encode messages in the "shortest form" and a collector or relay
>   MUST NOT interpret messages in the "non-shortest form".
>
> Inside PARAM-VALUE, the characters '"' (ABNF %d34), '\' (ABNF %d92),
>   and ']' (ABNF %d93) MUST be escaped.  This is necessary to avoid
>   parsing errors.  Escaping ']' would not strictly be necessary but is 
>   REQUIRED by this specification to avoid syslog application
>   implementation errors.  Each of these three characters MUST be 
>   escaped as '\"', '\\', and '\]' respectively.  The backslash is used
>   for control character escaping for consistency with its use for
>   escaping in other parts of the syslog message as well as in 
>   traditional syslog.
>
> A backslash ('\') followed by none of the three described characters
>   is considered an invalid escape sequence.  In this case, the backslash
>   MUST be treated as a regular backslash and the following character as
>   a regular character.  Thus, the invalid sequence MUST not be altered.

A space character can certainly be part of a "valid UTF-8 sequence".  The second quoted paragraph mentions three characters that must be escaped; the space character isn't one of them.

Conclusion: the `PARAM-VALUE` field can contain blanks.